# New badge suggestion - when your answer gets accepted (first time)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, badge-request

The "**Teacher**" badge is given for: Answering first question with score of 1 or more. However, the OP accepting an answer is significantly different from a general viewer up-voting a question. I suggest a new badge, say "**Troubleshooter**", awarded the first time when your answer is chosen as 'accepted answer' by an OP.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a very good idea. If nothing else, it should restore the symmetry between the starter badges for asking and the started badges for answering questions.

I would call the badge something other than "Troubleshooter", though. I think the name should be along the "Student"/"Scholar" lines. Since the badge for the first upvoted answer is called "Teacher", I would suggest calling the new badge "Mentor" or "Adviser".

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a good idea. This also teaches about the site features. There is a lot of different types of badges that can be awarded yet there isn't anything on first accepted answer? It's be nice to show a noob accomplishment.

Also, the category would belong to Answers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a good idea.

I think the general rule is that badges add value to the site if they either

- encourage positive behaviour (Like "Strunk & White" for editing)
- give users an incentive to explore the site's functions (Like "Investor" for bounties)

a badge for the first accepted answer wouldn't fall in either of these categories IMO. It wouldn't encourage any new behaviour (You will strive to write good answers anyway), and it wouldn't help you explore new functions (because you're not the one doing the accepting).

Comment: The "Teacher" badge also does not fall in the above category? Its just a 'pat-on-the-back', so could 'Troubleshooter' be.

Comment: @JP19 true - that one might be superfluous as well. It's like badges for reaching 1k, 3k, 10k points - the reward is already there, no need for a badge. There are already so many badges, I think one needs to be *very* careful about adding new ones

Comment: Ya - though I am not experienced enough to have a feel of the exact purpose of badges, if what you say is true (badges should encourage user to do something that they would not otherwise do), then Teacher badge sounds superflous.

Comment: @JP yeah. I have nothing against your suggestion per se, and a pat on the back is always nice, especially for new users. But look at the [badges page](http://stackoverflow.com/badges)... It is so awfully huge already. I think it needs no more "Everyone gets it" badges

Comment: Just like that, I think Tumbleweed is another such 'weedish' badge.

Comment: @JP19 the teacher badge is meant to encourage those who only post questions to post answers.  It is one of the "starter badges" to get people hooked onto the system.

Comment: I wonder why there's a Teacher Badge but no badge for accept.

Comment: @jp19 Tumbleweed at least shows that there is something in asking a question that doesn't get a lot of initial attention. A consolation. Next time a asking a question is being pondered, it might tip the balance to asking anyway, because "if I don't get an answer, at least I may end up with a badge", whereas the opposite side of the scale is not asking a new question for fear of it being ignored. Looking just now, I'm shocked there are so many :-)